# A question about Marino–Prodi perturbation

Tags: topological-groups, hilbert-spaces, calculus-of-variations, morse-theory

In this paper [N. Ghoussoub](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/crll.1991.417.27/html),
the author claims the following version of Marino–Prodi perturbation, that is :

Let $H$ a Hilbert space.
Let $f\in C^2(H, \mathbb{R}),$ $K$ is a compact subset of $K_c$ (that is, the set of critical points with critical value $c$) on which $d^2f$ is a Fredholm operator, for any $\epsilon_1>0$ and $\epsilon_2>0$ small enough, there exist a function $g\in C^2(H, \mathbb{R})$ such that :

- $\|f-g\|_{C^2}<\epsilon_1.$
- $f(x)=g(x)$ if $x$ outside $K^{2\epsilon_2}$, that is, $2\epsilon_2$-neighborhood of $K$.
- All the critical points of $g$ in $K^{\epsilon_2}$ are non-degenerate and finite in number.
- Moreover, If $f$ is $G$-invariant functional for a a topological group $G$ on $H$, then $g$ can be chosen to be $G$-invariant.

In particular, if $G=Z_2$, $f$ is even, hence $g$ is even.

The proof in [Solimini](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01171757.pdf) for the first three conclusions is given here:

- First construct a smooth cut-off function $\phi(x)$,  $\phi(x)$ equals $1$ on $K^{\epsilon_2}$,
  equals $0$ outside $K^{2\epsilon_2}$.
- Set $g(x)=f(x)+\phi(x)y.x$, then by Sard-Smale Theorem, choosing a small $y$ such that $-y$ is a regular value of $df$, hence we complete the proof of the first three conclusions.

However, my question is how to construct a $G$-invariant $g$ when $f$ is  $G$-invariant? In particularly, when $G=Z_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof for $G=Z_2$ is given in [jde2016](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jde.2016.09.018) Appendix B Proposition B3.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it [is better](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/295232) to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes or disappears.